# Calculate swap values dynamically

Tags: shell-script, command-substitution

Can someone please let me know if the following commands should work as I am not sure and am getting error?

Just to let you know that I am using this in one of my nagios scripts:

```
## GET SWAP Warning and Critical values from the Machine
temp=$(swapon -s | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}' ) 
SWAP_WARN=$(echo '$(temp)*.20' | bc) 
SWAP_CRIT=$(echo '$(temp)*.40' | bc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not post the error message but based on your source I figure issues in the way "temp" variable is dereferenced. You need to use braces instead of parentheses and finally wrap up in double quotes.

Try this.

```
temp=$(swapon -s | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}' )
SWAP_WARN=$(echo "${temp}*.20" | bc)
SWAP_CRIT=$(echo "${temp}*.40" | bc)
```

Comment: Hi Soumen,
I have got the below script and now using the same as advised but it is now reporting error for $ in line one .Can you please suggest... ? The script is below:

Comment: #!/bin/bash
#
# Returns the nagios native status codes:
# Nagios Status
# 0 = OK (SWAP usage below WARNING)
# 1 = WARNING (SWAP usage between WARNING AND CRITICAL)
# 2 = CRITICAL (SWAP usage higher than CRITICAL)
# 3 = UNKNOWN (Wrong usage)

PROGNAME=`basename $0`
PROGPATH=`echo $0 | sed -e 's,[\\/][^\\/][^\\/]*$,,'`

. $PROGPATH/utils.sh

SWAP_WARN=
SWAP_CRIT=
SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST=

## GET SWAP Warning and Critical values from the Machine

temp=$(swapon -s | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}' )
SWAP_WARN=$(echo '${temp}*.20' | bc)
SWAP_CRIT=$(echo '${temp}*.40' | bc)

The error is :

Comment: The error is
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $
(standard_in) 1: syntax error

Comment: I suggest you post the code in your original description. That way it will come out formatted. In its current form, I cannot make out anything. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I see that you have not used double quotes (") around "temp" expression. Please replace  '${temp}*.20' with "${temp}*.20" . Also, replace '${temp}*.40' with "${temp}*.40" . Or, you may choose to copy paste the source from my post.